# How to configure simple RabbitMQ message producer with Spring Integration

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-integration, amqp

I'd like to configure a simple RabbitMQ message producer using Spring Integration constructs. The requirement is very basic: just a simple fire-and-forget, sending an event message to a queue, no response required.
I've configured the connection factory, RabbitTemplate and outbound channel adapter (see below), but missing the last piece: the code that actually sends the message out to the channel.
Thanks in advance.

```
<rabbit:connection-factory id="producerRabbitConnectionFactory" 
        channel-cache-size="${amqp.channel.cache.size}"
        host="${amqp.hostname}"
        port="${amqp.port}" 
        virtual-host="${amqp.vhost}" 
        username="${amqp.username}"
        password="${amqp.password}"
        requested-heartbeat="${amqp.heartbeat}"
/>

<bean id="producerRabbitTemplate" class="org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate">
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="producerRabbitConnectionFactory" />
        <property name="exchange" value="${amqp.exchange.event}" />
        <property name="routingKey" value="${amqp.routingKey.event}" />
</bean>

<int:channel id="outboundAmqpChannel" />

<int-amqp:outbound-channel-adapter id="outboundAmqpChannelAdapter"
                               channel="outboundAmqpChannel"
                               amqp-template="producerRabbitTemplate"
                               default-delivery-mode="NON_PERSISTENT"
                               lazy-connect="true"/>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest is a [Messaging Gateway](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#gateway). That way your code doesn't know your talking to an integration flow.

```
public interface Foo {

    void bar(String foo);

}

<int:gateway service-interface="foo.Foo" default-request-channel="outboundAmqpChannel" />
```

Inject a `Foo` into your code and call it.